# How to make reply of an email becomes a HttpRequestServlet to a web application?

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I got a requirement which I don't know how to get started.

**Requirement:**

The application will send emails to clients (using org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender) with same "from email address" as support@mydomain.com. Also the email content will have some hidden information such as client_id. If the client reply back to that email, I need to get that as an HttpServletRequest to a Servlet so that I can process it.

EDIT:
This web application does not have google app engine setup, but my requirement is matching similar to [this link](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/receiving).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When someone replies to the mail you sent him that mail will go to the POP3 server configured for your domain. From this SMTP server you can read this mail using the Java Mail API. You can have a Spring timer task to keep polling this mailbox after every few seconds.

I would look at the below resources to see how to read mail from the POP3 server -

**Using JavaMail API -**

[http://metoojava.wordpress.com/2010/03/21/java-code-to-receive-mail-using-javamailapi](http://metoojava.wordpress.com/2010/03/21/java-code-to-receive-mail-using-javamailapi/)

**Using Spring -**

http://blog.solidcraft.eu/2011/04/read-emails-from-imap-with-spring.html

Comment: POP3 does not have to have anything to do with it in general.

Answer (score 0):

Better and popular solution is to have a link in your email and asking user to click it and asking specifically not to reply to this email (from address can be noreply@domain.com)

For getting a servlet call in an email reply, you need to use

http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/com/sun/mail/pop3/package-summary.html

Keep polling for new emails in your reply address(for  eg support@domain.com) using POP, and when new email comes trigger a httprequest(HttpClient? ).

On a related note you can add user_id and similar stuff using a `+` in reply email address
For eg `support@domain.com` and `support+uid_21_catid_32@domain.com` will deliver to same address. Everything after + is ignored. But you will get this info in reply email event as to address and decide on who is the user.This could be a security concern for sure if not properly implemented.